# What makes the String class in Kotlin to be able to work with square brackets?

Tags: kotlin, operator-overloading, indices

In Kotlin you can do something like this:

```kotlin
val s: String = "Hey"
println(s[1])
```

or simply:

```kotlin
println("Hey"[1])
```

and you will print `e`.

But what if you want to extend this behavior to your own classes? What interface do you need to implement to accomplish this syntax?

I looked at `String`'s supertypes and only found `Comparable<String>` and `CharSequence`, neither of which had any other supertypes themselves, so my quest ended early.

For example in Python, by defining a method called `__getitem__` in a class, you can bestow the objects of that class the ability to be used with square brackets syntax like this `a[i]`; I was wondering how this was possible in Kotlin.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FWIW, adding `__getitem__()`  to a class in Python enables **all square bracket `[]` access**, including strings (like for dicts), slices (like for lists), tuple of slices (like in pandas), and some mix-n-matches. Whatever is put in between the square brackets is passed in as the first parameter and must be interpreted according to its type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Kotlin's operator overloading, specifically the overloading for [indexed access operators](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html#indexed-access-operator).

The syntax `"Hey"[1]` is just an alias for `"Hey".get(1)` (if not on the left-hand side of an assignment, where it would be an alias for `"Hey".set(1, ...)`).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently just having a method `get(i: Int)` suffices. Interesting...

Comment: It has to be marked with `operator`.

Comment: @broot I tried it before posting that answer. `operator` is not required. Sadly.

Comment: Hmm, how did you verify this? `operator` is required: https://pl.kotl.in/-Xlu_LVDm I get the same results in IntelliJ.

Comment: @broot This is how I judged that it works in IntelliJ https://imgur.com/a/i92tEJI but apparently even though IntelliSense shows `coolName` within square brackets, the final code would not work without `operator`, so I was wrong.